# Use KTOR as a pipe for simultaneously fetching and responding a file

Tags: kotlin, pdf, stream, pipe, ktor

I have a KTOR backend which serves as a broker between the frontend-client and an external REST API. I want to make KTOR fetch the chunks of a file from the REST API, and as it receives these chunks KTOR should pass them on to the client, without having to temporarily store the entire file. The file can be very large, which is why the only option is to stream it.

I have made this simple illustration to show what I want to achieve:
[image]

I have something like this in my code so far, but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
get("/file") {

    val uri = "/rest-api"

    downloadFileClient.prepareGet(uri).execute {response ->
        call.respondOutputStream(ContentType.Application.Pdf, HttpStatusCode.OK, producer = {response.bodyAsChannel()})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can respond with an object of the `OutgoingContent.ReadChannelContent` class which can use client's response as a source:

```
get("/file") {
    val uri = "/rest-api"

    downloadFileClient.prepareGet(uri).execute { response ->
        val channel = response.bodyAsChannel()

        call.respond(object : OutgoingContent.ReadChannelContent() {
            override fun readFrom(): ByteReadChannel = channel
            override val status: HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            override val contentType: ContentType = ContentType.Application.Pdf
        })
    }
}
```